# How do I select a sibling element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

Can you help me with this jQuery selector?

```
$(".auctiondiv .auctiondivleftcontainer .countdown").each(function () {
    var newValue = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) - 1;
    $(this).text(newValue);

    if (newValue == 0) {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        chat.verify($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Basically, I want to select the element with .bidbutton class that belongs in the same parent as the .countdown in the each loop:

```
<div class="auctiondivleftcontainer">
    <p class="countdown">0</p>
    <button class="btn primary bidbutton">Lance</button>                            
</div>
```

And then apply this to that button:

```
$(button here).addClass("disabled");
$(button here).attr("disabled", "");
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Use jQuery [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to select the matching sibling.

```
$(this).siblings('.bidbutton');
```

Comment: `Siblings()` returns an array of *all* of the elements that match said selector.

Comment: How to get all siblings but not this ?

Answer (score 7):

```
$(this).siblings(".bidbutton")
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$("h2").siblings().css({"color": "blue"});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("selector").nextAll(); 
$("selector").prev();
```

you can also find an element using Jquery selector

```
$("h2").siblings('table').find('tr');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
you can use 
$(this).siblings(".bidbutton").addClass("disabled");
$(this).siblings(".bidbutton").attr("disabled","");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a specific sibling:

```
var $sibling = $(this).siblings('.bidbutton')[index];
```

where 'index' is the index of the specific sibling within the parent container.

Comment: Only useful if you know the index ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$(this)` refers to `.countdown` you can use `$(this).next()` or `$(this).next('button')` more specifically.

Comment: And what if it isn't right next to him? what if it's behind him? Use the more general siblings solution.

Comment: Amazingly, it IS in his provided DOM and there's no reason to traverse ALL the siblings if he doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
   $(this).siblings(".bidbutton").addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

also if you need to select a sibling with a name rather than the class, you could use the following

```
var $sibling = $(this).siblings('input[name=bidbutton]');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood that correctly you're already in a loop (each) so you would always want to select that **one** sibling button inside each loop runthrough?
Since **siblings()** returns an array, this would be the way to go:

```
$(this).siblings('.bidbutton')[0]
```

You can apply both things you wanted in a single line doing this:

```
$(this).siblings('.bidbutton')[0].addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "");
```